# How to use set_languages using langid LanguageIdentifier

Tags: python

I am trying to specify which languages to use. In the example below I define Dutch and French. According to the langid documentation it should classify the comment as one of these two languages, but instead it gives me English as a result. I'm not sure if I use the set_languages function correctly. What am I doing wrong?

```
from langid.langid import LanguageIdentifier, model, set_languages


comment = 'I am trying to test the set_languages function in the langid package'
set_languages(langs=['nl','fr'])
language_identifier = LanguageIdentifier.from_modelstring(model, norm_probs=True)
lang_id = language_identifier.classify(comment)
```

This returns:

```
('en', 1.0)
```

Answer (score 1):

A little late, but I had the same problem, and looking at langid sources, it seems the global set_languages function affects only the global instance of LanguageIdentifier (inside langid.py) and so the correct way to set languages for one's own instance is to call set_languages method on that, i.e.

```
language_identifier.set_languages(langs=['nl','fr'])
```

in the example above.